# Select group of rows that match all items in a list

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, relational-division

Assume I have two tables:

`cars` – list of cars

```
carname | modelnumber | ...
```

`passedtest` – contains every test that a car passed:

```
id | carname | testtype | date | ...
1  | carA    | A        | 2000 |
2  | carB    | C        | 2000 |
3  | carC    | D        | 2001 |
4  | carA    | C        | 2002 |
```

Now, how can I select a car from the `passedtest` table that passed all tests (A, B, C, D)?

I tried the `IN` statement but it also matches cars that pass even one test. I am looking for a statement to match *all* values in a list across all rows.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

How about this?

```
SELECT carname
FROM PassedTest
GROUP BY carname
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT testtype) = 4
```

You can also use it as an inner statement for taking info from the `cars` table:

```
SELECT *
FROM cars
WHERE carname IN (
    SELECT carname
    FROM PassedTest
    GROUP BY carname
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT testtype) = 4
)
```

Comment: thanks but the output i have is repeated i think because to create cars table i used inner join

Comment: However, this won't work with wildcards, since in such case the explicit count can not be established.

Comment: but we're hard coding the value of 4... what if we add a test?

Comment: @Dangel -- Having count(distinct testtype)=(select count(distinct testtype) from cars)

Answer (score 49):

This type of problem is called `Relational Division`.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    Cars a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  CarName
            FROM    PassedTest 
            WHERE   testType IN ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')
            GROUP   BY CarName
            HAVING  COUNT(*) = 4
        ) b ON a.CarName = b.CarName
```

if a `UNIQUE` constraint was not enforce on `TestType` for every `CarName` on table `PassedTest` a `DISTINCT` keyword is required on `COUNT()` so it will only count unique values.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    Cars a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  CarName
            FROM    PassedTest 
            WHERE   testType IN ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')
            GROUP   BY CarName
            HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT TestType) = 4
        ) b ON a.CarName = b.CarName
```

- [SQL of Relational Division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)

but if you are only interested on the `CARNAME` then you don't need to join the tables. Querying on table `PassedTest` will suit your needs.

```
SELECT  CarName
FROM    PassedTest 
WHERE   testType IN ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')
GROUP   BY CarName
HAVING  COUNT(*) = 4
```

Answer (score 15):

You want to perform relational division, an operation that is not implemented in SQL. Here is an example where we have a **product-supplier** table and a **required-products** table:

```
CREATE TABLE product_supplier (
    product_id int NOT NULL,
    supplier_id int NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (product_id, supplier_id)
);
INSERT INTO product_supplier (product_id, supplier_id) VALUES
(1, 1),
(2, 1),
(3, 1),
(1, 2),
(2, 2),
(3, 2),
(4, 2),
(2, 3),
(3, 3),
(4, 3);

CREATE TABLE reqd (
    product_id int NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (product_id)
);
INSERT INTO reqd (product_id) VALUES
(1),
(2),
(3);
```

... and we want to find all suppliers that supply ALL required products and perhaps others. The result in the above example would be supplier 1 and 2.

The most straight forward solution is this:

```
SELECT product_supplier.supplier_id
FROM product_supplier
LEFT JOIN reqd ON product_supplier.product_id = reqd.product_id
GROUP BY product_supplier.supplier_id
HAVING COUNT(reqd.product_id) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM reqd);
```

```
+-------------+
| supplier_id |
+-------------+
|           1 |
|           2 |
+-------------+
```

And if we want to find all suppliers that supply ALL required products and no others (exact division/no remainder) then add one more condition to the above:

```
SELECT product_supplier.supplier_id
FROM product_supplier
LEFT JOIN reqd ON product_supplier.product_id = reqd.product_id
GROUP BY product_supplier.supplier_id
HAVING COUNT(reqd.product_id) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM reqd)
AND COUNT(product_supplier.product_id) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM reqd);
```

```
+-------------+
| supplier_id |
+-------------+
|           1 |
+-------------+
```

An alternate solution is to rephrase the problem: select suppliers where a required product does not exist that does not exist in the products supplied by the supplier. Hmmm:

```
SELECT DISTINCT supplier_id
FROM product_supplier AS ps1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM reqd
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM product_supplier AS ps2
        WHERE ps1.supplier_id = ps2.supplier_id AND ps2.product_id = reqd.product_id
    )
);
```

```
+-------------+
| supplier_id |
+-------------+
|           1 |
|           2 |
+-------------+
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it doesn't requiring hardcoding values