# search pk have a AND b

Tags: sql, sql-server, relational-database, relationship

How can I achieve something like:
"Any employee with Present AND Latein status"

My tables is like this

```
employee
+--------+---------+
| emp_id | name    |
+--------+---------+
| a001   | michael |
+--------+---------+
| a002   | john    |
+--------+---------+

status
+--------+---------+
| emp_id | status  |
+--------+---------+
| a001   | Present |
+--------+---------+
| a001   | Latein  |
+--------+---------+
| a002   | Absence |
+--------+---------+
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server - select rows that match all items in a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15977126/sql-server-select-rows-that-match-all-items-in-a-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select e.name
from employee e
join status s on s.emp_id = e.emp_id
where s.status in ('Present', 'Latein')
group by e.emp_id, e.name
having count(*) = 2
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use an inner join on a derived table from status:

```
SELECT name
FROM employee E
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT emp_Id
    FROM status 
    WHERE status IN('Present', 'Latein')
    GROUP BY emp_Id
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
) D 
ON E.emp_Id = D.emp_Id
```

The derived table will include only those employees that have records with both `Present` and `Latein`.

Answer (score 2):

Use condtional aggregation on the `status` table to determine which employees have `'Present'` and `'Latein'`.  Then join this result to the `employee` table to get the matching names.

```
SELECT t1.emp_id, t1.name
FROM employee t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT emp_id,
        SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'Present' OR status = 'Latein'
                 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS statusSum
    FROM status
    GROUP BY emp_id
    HAVING statusSum = 2
) t2
    ON t1.emp_id = t2.emp_id
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are looking for Latein employees. If they are late, they must be present, otherwise they did not come and are Absent. 
So for you it is best to use

`SELECT emp_id FROM status WHERE status='Latein'`