# Best SQL query to retrieve the data which has all required data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a transaction table with item details for each company. I want to write a query to retrieve the companies only having item numbers 1,2 and 3 (according to my sample code in below). Selected companies should have all 1,2,3 items. If some company has only item 1, then it shouldn't come. How can I write this?

```
CREATE TABLE #TmpTran 
(
     ID BIGINT IDENTITY, 
     COMPANY_ID BIGINT, 
     ITEM_NAME VARCHAR(50), 
     ITEM_NUMBER INT
)

INSERT INTO #TmpTran (COMPANY_ID, ITEM_NAME, ITEM_NUMBER)
VALUES (1, 'ABC', 1), (1, 'DEF', 2), (1, 'HIJ', 3),
       (2, 'KLM', 4), (2, 'KLM', 5), (2, 'ABC', 1)
```

How can I get only Company 1 data using `WHERE` or `JOIN` query?

Comment: What should happen when there is a company with 1,2,3 and 4 item numbers, will that company be part of result ?

Comment: yes... because that company has all  the items (1,2,3 in this example) we search for. I want to load all the companies which are having all the search items.

Comment: Then I will prefer Gordon's answer..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server - select rows that match all items in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15977126/sql-server-select-rows-that-match-all-items-in-a-list)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with `group by` and `having`:

```
select company_id
from #tmptran tt
where item_number in (1, 2, 3)
group by company_id
having count(distinct item_number) = 3;
```

Comment: could you please explain me "count(distinct item_number) = 3;" here? why 3 is hard coded.

Comment: @user2837480 : In this query you first get all the ***rows*** that have an `item_number` of 1, 2 or 3, then `GROUP` all those rows together by `company_id`.  In your sample data `company_id = 1` will have 3 such matching rows, and `company_id = 2` will have just 1 such matching row.  `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT item_number)` is like a second `WHERE` applied after the `GROUP BY`.  This one counts how many distinct item_numbers each company_id has *(distinct is used in case a company the same item_number more than once)*.  The 3 is hard coded because you're searching for 3 different item_numbers.

Comment: @user2837480 . . . The `count(distinct)` ensures that all three values are there for each company.  The "3" is the number of values you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Another way (more flexible approach)

```
select company_id
from #tmptran tt
group by company_id
having count(case when item_number = 1 then 1 end) > 0;
   and count(case when item_number = 2 then 1 end) > 0;
   and count(case when item_number = 3 then 1 end) > 0;
```

Comment: Necessitates a full table scan, which isn't always necessary.  Sometimes the full table scan happens anyway, but @GordonLinoff's answer there is at least the possibility that it won't happen.

Comment: Shouldn't this be: count(case when item_number = 1 then 1 end) > 0 and...

Comment: actually im sending required item numbers in temp table. I have concern like im returning around 20 amount of columns data. So put them all in a group by section will be a mess. You have any other solution? Thanks for helping!

Comment: @user2837480 - Please update you question with a concrete example?  Including input data and expected results?

Answer (score 1):

```
select tt.company_id
from #tmptran tt
where tt.item_number in (1, 2, 3)
group by tt.company_id
having sum(max(case tt.item_number when 1 then 1 end)) +
   and sum(max(case tt.item_number when 2 then 1 end)) +
   and sum(max(case tt.item_number when 3 then 1 end)) = 3
```

Comment: At present the `HAVING` clause does the same job as the `WHERE` clause, as well as some extra necessary work.  That makes the `WHERE` clause redundant, or the `HAVING` clause overly complex.  I would recommend either removing the `WHERE` clause or changing the `HAVING` clause to be `COUNT(DISTINCT item_number) = 3`

Answer (score 0):

You said you have a lot of fields.  Probably the easiest for the reader to follow would be something like:

```
select distinct tt.company_id
from #tmptran tt
where tt.item_number in (1, 2, 3)
and exists(select 1 
           from #tmptran ttSub 
           where ttSub.company_id = tt.company_id and ttSub.item_number = 1)
and exists(select 1 
           from #tmptran ttSub 
           where ttSub.company_id = tt.company_id and ttSub.item_number = 2)
and exists(select 1 
           from #tmptran ttSub 
           where ttSub.company_id = tt.company_id and ttSub.item_number = 3)
```