# select record only if specific related values are provided in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I 3 have tables, 2(`A` and `B`) of them have many to many relationship, they connected through pivot `C` table. tables desc:

```
A(id, name)
B(id, is_required)
C(a_id, b_id)
```

I want to select records from `A` table, which related record ids from `B` table are in provided input and fit some condition. for example:
lest say I have list of integers(ids) `[1,2,3,4,8,12]` and also one record from `A` has 5 related records from `B`, example:

```
A
id    name
1     test
-------------
B
id   is_required
1    true
2    true
3    false
10   false
16   false
```

I need to select records from table `A` join related records from table `B`, and check - if all required(`is_required = true`) record ids from `B` exists in my list (`[1,2,3,4,8,12]`) then we select this record, otherwise not. so the first example should be selected, because all required records from `B` (1 and 2) exists in list. for example this:

```
A
id    name
2     test2
-------------
B
id   is_required
1    true
2    true
5    true
6    false
```

should not be selected, because required record with id 5 not provided in list. how can I implement this in mysql? query example:

```
SELECT A.id, A.name FROM A, B, C
WHERE A.id = C.a_id
AND  C.b_id = B.id
```

as you see, for now its only joins related data, I really don't know how should I implement this. can you please help me?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15977126/select-rows-that-match-all-items-in-a-list

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you need `NOT EXISTS`

```
select A.*
from A
where not exists(
  select 1
  from C
  join B on C.b_id = B.id and
            A.id = C.a_id and
            is_required = 'false'
)
```

Comment: thanks, I tried similar thing, but where in this example I should check if `B.id` exists in provided ids?

Comment: @devnullΨ I think that it is not 100% what are your inputs and expected outputs. You should specify all tables (C as well), your input (provided B.ids?) and expected output for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select c.a_id
from c join
     b
     on c.b_id = b.id and b.is_required = 'true'
group by c.a_id
having count(*) = (select count(*) from b where b.is_required = 'true');
```