# Filtering Results Based on Like Categories Through Intermediate Table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, join

I'm trying to filter through categories assigned to topics based on which categories are assigned to each topic. I have three tables, a topic table (id, name), a category table (id, name), and a table that bridges the two table in a one-to-many relationship (id, topic_id, category_id).

For instance, I have a list of rides and shows at popular theme parks (Space Mountain, Thunder Mountain, It's a Small World, The Haunted Mansion, Tower Of Terror, Test Track, etc.), a list of categories (Magic Kingdom, Epcot, Animal Kingdom, Thrill Rides, Shows, Family Rides, Boat Rides, etc.), and an intermediate table linking them ((1,1,3), (1,1,5), (1,2,5), etc.).

[SQLFiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/153f5/3)

I've got the basic query constructed for input of a single category, but I cannot figure out how to filter using multiple categories. For example, If I query categories 'magic-kingdom' AND 'nighttime-shows', that would filter out categories such as 'epcot', and 'thrill-rides'.

My query is as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT scat.name FROM category AS cat 
JOIN bridge ON cat.id = bridge.cat_id 
JOIN topic ON bridge.top_id = topic.id 
JOIN bridge AS sbridge ON topic.id = sbridge.top_id 
JOIN category AS scat ON sbridge.cat_id = scat.id 
WHERE cat.slug = 'hollywood-studios' 
ORDER BY scat.name ASC
```

Thank's for the help in advance!

Comment: udpate your question add  proper data sample and the expected  result  .. not only sqlfiddle

Comment: Can you not just add `OR cat.slug = 'nighttime-shows' ` to your `WHERE`?

Comment: Are you saying that 'magic-kingdom' + 'nighttime-shows' should filter out epcot? and thrill-rides? I just need some test cases but i think i got it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15977126/select-rows-that-match-all-items-in-a-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood, you need categories that match topics that match ALL of the filter categories.
You simply have to fill in the list of matching categories, and hardcode their count. Now it's `2`

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  cat.name
FROM bridge b
JOIN category cat
  ON b.cat_id = cat.id
WHERE b.top_id IN (
  SELECT
    b.top_id
  FROM bridge b
  JOIN category c
    ON c.id = b.cat_id
  WHERE c.slug IN ('magic-kingdom', 'nighttime-shows')
  GROUP BY b.top_id
  HAVING count(b.cat_id) = 2
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use OR in where clause to filter records of multiple categories like

```
SELECT DISTINCT scat.name FROM category AS cat 
JOIN bridge ON cat.id = bridge.cat_id 
JOIN topic ON bridge.top_id = topic.id 
JOIN bridge AS sbridge ON topic.id = sbridge.top_id 
JOIN category AS scat ON sbridge.cat_id = scat.id 
WHERE cat.slug = 'hollywood-studios' OR cat.slug = 'fireworks-shows'  
ORDER BY scat.name ASC
```