# How to select particular column from table if another column includes all the set of requested values?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table in MySQL named `table1` which has three columns `id`, `user_id`(foreign_key) and `destination_id`(foreign_key). One user can have multiple destinations.

```
E.g Table1

id      user_id       destination_id
1         10            2
2          5            3
3         10            4
4         10            5
5          9            10
6          5            12
7          8            2
```

I get a request from the client side in PHP script; the request includes destination ids in an array.

```
E.g. $request = array('destination_id' => [2,4,5]);
```

I just want to get all the user_id from table1 if and only if the particular user_id contains all requested destinations.

I tried to achieve this using 'IN' operator. 
i.e.

```
     SELECT user_id FROM table1 WHERE destination_id IN ($requestedDestinationsInCommaSeparatedString)
```

It gives row including user_id 8 along with user_id 10 but I just need user_id 10. I just wanted to know the concept regarding the solution to the following problem. I am a beginner in SQL, any help would be very appreciable. Thanks.

Comment: You had better show us how you created `$requestedDestinationsInCommaSeparatedString` from that array

Comment: In your case, you cannot use IN, because IN will tell the query to look for any user_id that fit on ANY of the destination_id you provided.

Comment: Can I check that you really mean this statement _if the particular user_id contains_ **all** _requested destinations_

Comment: See this, Niraj. Seems exactly like your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15977126/select-rows-that-match-all-items-in-a-list

Comment: @RiggsFolly: $requestedDestinationsInCommaSeparatedString just means the conversion result of requested destination array into string so that it fit inside IN operator in mysql. For example: In above scenario, it is  $requestedDestinationsInCommaSeparatedString = "2,4,5".

Comment: @RafaelBoszko Thanks. It was the similar issue I faced.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check that a user_id refers to all requested destination by grouping and counting the destinations.

```
SELECT user_id
FROM table1 
WHERE
    destination_id IN (2,4,5)
GROUP BY
    user_id
HAVING count(*) = 3
-- count must be the number of elments in (2,4,5)
```

For doing so, the field combination of user_id and destination_id must be unique over all records.

Comment: Thank you I will try this approach.

Comment: Thanks @Henrik :)

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is to use multiple subselects and build the query string in PHP.

So for your specific example the SQL-Query-String generated should be

```
SELECT user_id
FROM table1 

WHERE user_id IN
    (SELECT user_id FROM table1 WHERE destination_id = 2)
AND user_id IN
    (SELECT user_id FROM table1 WHERE destination_id = 4)
AND user_id IN
    (SELECT user_id FROM table1 WHERE destination_id = 5)

GROUP BY user_id
```

I think programming the function which generates the middle part for you shouldn't be too hard.