# SQL Query to conditionally retrieve records based on a key value list

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have an API that communicates with a database with the following tables:

**QUESTS**

```
+----------+------------+
| quest_id | quest_name |
+----------+------------+
|        1 | Q001       |
|        2 | Q002       |
|        3 | Q003       |
|        4 | Q004       |
|        5 | Q005       |
+----------+------------+
```

**SKILLS**

```
+----------+------------+
| skill_id | skill_name |
+----------+------------+
|        1 | S001       |
|        2 | S002       |
|        3 | S003       |
|        4 | S004       |
|        5 | S005       |
+----------+------------+
```

**SKILL_PREREQUISITES**

```
+----------+-----------------------+-------------+
| quest_id | prerequisite_skill_id | skill_value |
+----------+-----------------------+-------------+
|        1 |                     2 |          50 |
|        1 |                     1 |          45 |
|        4 |                     2 |          25 |
|        4 |                     3 |          60 |
|        5 |                     4 |          50 |
+----------+-----------------------+-------------+
```

Quests correspond to levels in a game, and the skills are acquired by players while playing the game. The `SKILL_PREREQUISITE` table maintains the skill pre-requisites a player needs to satisfy before being able to participate in a quest.

**Problem**

An endpoint of the API receives a list of skills a player has, along with the skill level (skill_value) of the corresponding skill like so:

```
[
{
  "key": 1, //skill ID
  "value": 45 //skill value
},
{
  "key": 2,
  "value": 60
}
...
]
```

**Now my use case is** to use these values and query the database to obtain a list of Quests the player is eligible to participate in based on the `skill_id` as well as the `skill_value`

**Example**

Assume the API receives the following skill-skill value mapping:

```
skill-value map: [{1,50}, {2,60}, {4,50}]
```

Based on this, the player with the above skill set can participate in quest 1 and 5 but not in 4 since 4 requires skill 3 with 60 points.

**Attempt at a solution**

I have managed to write a query (thanks to a previous question I posted!) to identify the quests that correspond to the skill IDs, but I have no idea how to filter this further within the query, based on the skill value.

I am wondering if this is even possible at this point and whether I might have to do further processing on the server to get the required result.

Fiddle for my attempt at a solution: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/s2umHS1wz3Q8ibwUhKDas6/1

Comment: It's not that much important but i would still like to know how you're passing these skill_id and skill_values parsed from API response to your database query?

Comment: I am not yet, I need to finalize the query and based on that, I will parse the request body as required

Comment: what backend platform you're using? Is it JAVA? C#?

Comment: Node with sequelize for mysql

Comment: So the accepted answer is working correctly if there are more `skill-id` in skill-value map?

Comment: @ Harshil Doshi  I dynamically generate the SUM.. sql statements while parsing the request body. SO yes it does work. Thank you for your answer as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can phrase the query by comparing both the skill and the value:

```
SELECT q.quest_id
FROM QUESTS q LEFT JOIN
     SKILL_PREREQUISITES p
     ON p.quest_id = q.quest_id
GROUP BY q.quest_id
HAVING SUM( p.prerequisite_skill_id = 1 and 50 >= p.skill_value) > 0 AND
       SUM( p.prerequisite_skill_id = 2 and 60 >= p.skill_value) > 0 AND
       SUM( p.prerequisite_skill_id = 4 and 50 >= p.skill_value) > 0 ;
```

Because you need quests that have prerequisites, a `LEFT JOIN` is not necessary.  In fact, no `JOIN` is necessary at all:

```
SELECT p.quest_id
FROM SKILL_PREREQUISITES p
WHERE p.prerequisite_skill_id IN (1, 2, 4)
GROUP BY p.quest_id
HAVING SUM( p.prerequisite_skill_id = 1 and 50 >= p.skill_value) > 0 AND
       SUM( p.prerequisite_skill_id = 2 and 60 >= p.skill_value) > 0 AND
       SUM( p.prerequisite_skill_id = 4 and 50 >= p.skill_value) > 0 ;
```

The filtering before the `GROUP BY` is optional, but it might improve performance.

EDIT:

I think I answered the wrong question above.  I think you want all the skills that are available given the user's pre-requisites.  That would be:

```
SELECT q.quest_id
FROM QUESTS q LEFT JOIN
     SKILL_PREREQUISITES p
     ON p.quest_id = q.quest_id
GROUP BY q.quest_id
HAVING COALESCE(SUM( (p.prerequisite_skill_id = 1 and 50 >= p.skill_value) +
                     (p.prerequisite_skill_id = 2 and 60 >= p.skill_value) +
                     (p.prerequisite_skill_id = 4 and 50 >= p.skill_value)
                   )) = COUNT(p.prerequisite_skill_id);
```

Comment: Thank you! So basically the SUM.. statements should be dynamically generated on the server based on the key-value array that is received by the API?

Comment: This returns an empty set though on the fiddle

Comment: @fsociety . . . Obviously.  None of the quests in your fiddle have all three pre-requisites, much less meeting the value threshold.  It works if you modify the examples with appropriate data:  https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tD8671kgwx4M5knVRkbd5f/0.  But I think I answered the wrong question anyway.  I added an edit to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The challenge here is that you need to pass these values retrieved from an API response to your SQL statement as input and generate output by dynamically creating no of comparisons based on the input.

Now, if i would've familiar with your back-end platform than i would've given more apt solution but as i don't aware with Node.js, my solution will only include required SQL statements and the remaining part you need to DIY.

First thing you need to do is to parse this API response and store these values into a Data Structure.

Now, create a `Temporary table` in from your `Node.js` code and store these input values in this table.

```
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Input (id INT, value INT);
```

Add data from that Data structure to this table.

Now, run the following query & you'll get what you want:

```
SELECT skp.quest_id
FROM SKILL_PREREQUISITES skp 
GROUP BY quest_id
HAVING COUNT(skp.quest_id) =
                     ( SELECT COUNT(quest_id)
                       FROM Input i
                       JOIN SKILL_PREREQUISITES sp
                       ON sp.prerequisite_skill_id = i.id
                       AND sp.skill_value <= i.value
                       WHERE skp.quest_id = sp.quest_id
                      )
```

[Demo Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3y83kjnTaaPj7esa4LouRN/0)