# Lookup rows using pairs of values and find exact matching groups

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, relational-division

I have these tables:

**Project**

| id | name | version |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Pete | 0.0.1 |
| 2 | Swag | 0.0.1 |
| 3 | Swag | 0.0.2 |
| 4 | Swag | 0.0.3 |
| 5 | Kale | 0.0.1 |
| 6 | Kale | 0.0.2 |

**Person**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Jake |
| 2 | Skye |
| 3 | Kieth |
| 4 | Jim |
| 5 | Eliz |

**Person_Project**

| id | person_id | project_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 | 1 |
| 5 | 3 | 3 |
| 6 | 4 | 1 |
| 7 | 4 | 4 |
| 8 | 5 | 1 |
| 9 | 5 | 2 |
| 10 | 5 | 5 |

Persons will have unique projects, means no two persons will work on the same projects.

I am writing a java based api where I receive a json request with different projects and I have to return the person who is working on exact projects given in request.

Request:

```
[
    {"name": "Pete", "version": "0.0.1"}
]
```

This should return `Jake`

Request:

```
[
    {"name": "Pete", "version": "0.0.1"},
    {"name": "Swag", "version": "0.0.1"}
]
```

This should return `Skye`

Request:

```
[
    {"name": "Pete", "version": "0.0.1"},
    {"name": "Swag", "version": "0.0.2"}
]
```

This should return `Kieth`

I am writing SQL for this and not getting what I needed.

This is what I am up to

```
SELECT pe.id, pe.name
FROM person pe
LEFT JOIN person_project pepr on pepr.person_id = pe.id
WHERE pe.id IN (
    SELECT pepr.person_id
    FROM project pr
    LEFT JOIN person_project pepr ON pepr.project_id = pr.id
    WHERE pr.name IN ('Pete', 'Swag') AND pr.version IN ('0.0.1', '0.0.2')
    GROUP BY pepr.project_id
    HAVING COUNT(pepr.project_id) = 2
)
GROUP BY pe.id, pe.name
HAVING COUNT(pe.id) = 2
```

This is not right as I am using IN for versions which will gets applied to other projects.

Comment: I dont understand. I see many people working on project 1 so why should it return just Jake for example?

Comment: @SalmanA i am looking for person who only working project 1. I need exact match not IN search

Comment: And what about second example, with two projects?

Comment: in the second request I am looking for a person who is exactly working on project 1 and project 2. Third request is little different where request project 3 instead of project 2 as the version is 0.0.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SQL relational division logic as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15977126/select-group-of-rows-that-match-all-items-in-a-list/48720436#48720436). You're interested in the part that says exact division/no remainder:

```
with project_list as (
    select id
    from project
    where exists (
        select *
        from (values
            ('pete', '0.0.1'),
            ('swag', '0.0.1')
        ) as user_input(name, version)
        where project.name = user_input.name and project.version = user_input.version
    )
), person_project_copy as (
    select person_id, case when project_list.id is not null then 1 end as is_required
    from person_project
    left join project_list on person_project.project_id = project_list.id
)
select person_id
from person_project_copy
group by person_id
having count(is_required) = (select count(*) from project_list)
and    count(*)           = (select count(*) from project_list)
```

[DB<>Fiddle for all three examples](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f869a110073c44a53861e63c1ef2e242)

Comment: It returning Person 1 even for bad data

Comment: No idea then. Works for your sample data.

Comment: I mean when ('pete', '0.0.1'), ('swag', '0.0.5') it returns Person 1 instead of no records. Looks like it found Person only based on pete 0.0.1 and not considered swag 0.0.5 as it doesn't exist

Comment: (Revised) Handling this case is trivial. I have added a workaround here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2455ba9258bae7c8356ff519da5aa4e0 (see 4th example).

Answer (score 0):

**This is a classic [Relational Division Without Remainder](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/t-sql-programming-sql-server/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/) question.**

Start by placing your input data into a table variable or a Table Valued Parameter or a temp table.

Then you can use one of the standard relational division answers

```sql
SELECT
  p.name
FROM Person p
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM Person_Project pp
    LEFT JOIN @input i
        JOIN Project prj ON prj.name = i.name AND prj.version = i.version
      ON pp.project_id = prj.id
    WHERE pp.person_id = p.id
    HAVING COUNT(prj.id) = COUNT(*)
       AND COUNT(prj.id) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @input)
);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fd00789636de004ea632c9da7dbd2f98)

What this does is the following:

- Take all `Person` rows where the following `EXISTS` subquery is true:
- For each `Person` take all their `Person_Project` rows
- Left-join the input data (joining the matching `Project` at the same time).
- Group it up and ensure that the number of matches from the join is equal to the number of rows in the subquery...
- ... and the number is also equal to the total number of input rows.

There are other solutions to this also.